# How to use the saved .rds h2o model for prediction afterwards?

Tags: r, h2o

I have created a R model using mlr and h2o package as below

```
library(h2o)
rfh20.lrn = makeLearner("classif.h2o.randomForest", predict.type = "prob")
```

Done the model tunings and model initiates h2o JVM and connects R to h2o cluster, modelling is done and I saved the model as .rds file.

```
saveRDS(h2orf_mod, "h2orf_mod.rds")
```

I do the prediction as

```
pred_h2orf <- predict(h2orf_mod, newdata = newdata)
```

then i shutdown h2o

```
h2o.shutdown()
```

Later I re-call the saved model

```
h2orf_mod <- readRDS("h2orf_mod.rds")
```

Initiate h2o so JVM connects R to h2o cluster

```
h2o.init()
```

Now the model is from local saved location, cluster doesn't know the model, when i do prediction, I get error which is obvious

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/4/Predictions/models/DRF_model_R_1553297204511_743/frames/data.frame_sid_b520_1)

water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException: Object 'DRF_model_R_1553297204511_743' not found in function: predict for argument: model"
Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page, : ERROR MESSAGE: Object 'DRF_model_R_1553297204511_743' not found in function: predict for argument: model
```

May I know how to handle this, whether the saved model uploaded to cluster or something else, as every time building the model is NOT the effective way.

Comment: You should use `h2o.saveModel` and `h2o.loadModel` to save/load a model (and not the standard `saveRDS`/`readRDS` for an ordinary R object).

Answer (score 3):

As per the comment instead of saving model using saveDRS/readRDS, save model as

```
h2oModelsaved <- h2o.saveModel(object = h2orf_model, path = "C:/User/Models/")
```

Re-call model

```
h2o.init()
h2oModelLoaded <- h2o.loadModel(h2oModelsaved)
```

Convert the test data as h2o Frame

```
newdata <- as.h2o(testdata)
```

Then Call the predict

```
pred_h2orf2 <- predict(h2oModelLoaded, newdata = newdata)
```

This works perfect